# What is the SKYPE_TOOLBAR meta?

Tags: meta-tags

I need to make an audit for a website and I discovered a "new" meta called "SKYPE_TOOLBAR", it looks like that:

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

I've never seen that before and I don't manage to find relevant info about it, does someone know what is its use?

PS. There is nothing else related to Skype on the website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a vendor-specific tag to stop an addon Skype installs in Internet Explorer from highlighting phone numbers it detects in web documents. See a reference as [solution 3 in this blog post](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/web-development/prevent-skype-from-highlighting-phone-numbers/). From other mentions I've run across, it may not even work (anymore?) or is at least flaky. At any rate, it's safe to remove overall.

Answer (score 11):

Do not remove this. Someone has put it there for a purpose.

Its useful because people (often unknowingly) install the Skype toolbar, which horribly throws out the design of a website in many instances.

I add that code to all of the websites I build, because you just get complaints or problems somewhere down the track.

As of today's date, this solution still works for me.

Comment: Aug 2015: I just tested that inserting `<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE">` into your page head still disables the Skype phone number highlighting. I installed Skype Click To Call plug-in and enabled it in IE11. A test webpage with phone numbers in it, has the tags modified by the window.SkypeClick2Call object (which is inserted into the page by the plug-in). Added the meta tag into the test page head and the phone numbers are no longer modified (neither is the window.SkypeClick2Call object injected).